# CMake can not find package

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

I am trying to compile avro-c 1.9.1 on Ubuntu 19.04. CMake fails with

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:188 (message):
  libjansson >=2.3 not found
```

The section of `CMakeLists.txt` is

```
# Jansson JSON library
pkg_check_modules(JANSSON jansson>=2.3)
if (JANSSON_FOUND)
    set(JANSSON_PKG libjansson)
    include_directories(${JANSSON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${JANSSON_LIBRARY_DIRS})
else (JANSSON_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "libjansson >=2.3 not found")
endif (JANSSON_FOUND)
```

`apt` tells the following about the library:

```
$ apt list libjansson-dev
Listing... Done
libjansson-dev/disco,now 2.12-1build1 amd64 [installed]
```

I suspect that the string `2.12-1build1` fails to match some pattern, and thus CMake can not detect the package. I have tried to remove the version check, but that does not change anything.
Now I want to simply remove the check and set the relevant variables by hand instead. I would very much appreciate if someone could point me to what to write that would set the variables appropriately.

Comment: `pkg_check_modules` uses `pkg-config` utility for locate the module (library). Have you tried to run this utility alone, without CMake? `pkg-config jansson`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Tsyvarev for your comment. `pkg-config` was not installed on my system.